# How to tune response variable for neural network in r

Tags: r, neural-network

I have a training dataset with a set of features, observations and also response variable as following:

```
Obs=15
feature=10
dat<-data.frame()
   for( i in 1:Obs){
    d<-rnorm(feature,-1,1)
    dat<-rbind(dat,d)
   }
dat$y<-sample(0:1,Obs,replace = T)
```

If we suppose some of "y" has more impact, how we can tune neural network to highlight these variable.

Comment: Please check the code, it is not returning the dataset.

Comment: Your dataset is having only one y. You want to determine the variable importance of y (dependent variable) or independent variables.

Comment: This data set is a small portion of my main, but the generic idea is that, some of the y variable has more impact rather than other. I want to force neural network to highlight the y variable with more impact.

Comment: What are your dependent and independent variables? I suppose y is your dependent variable and rest are independent variables.

Comment: Thank you. I change my question , it is not the matter of name because my algorithm design in this way ...if I call y as dependent variable, I would like to force neural network with the respect to y variable.